# Regular expression PHP

Tags: php, regex

I just started to learn regular expression and i have one example like this 
' 23.0003NOV14DIX '. I want to extract 23.00 and 03NOV14DIX.

I tried this:

```
       preg_match("/(?P<a>[0-9]\.[0-9]{2}+)\s+"
           ."(?P<supplierPrice>)[^\s]\s+/"

       , $line, $matches);
```

But it is not working. My idea was that extract digits until met character '.' and then another 2 digits and the rest

Comment: Have you looked at the PHP docs for `preg_match`? http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following works.

`\s*(?P<a>\d+\.\d{2})(?P<supplierPrice>[^\s]+)\s*`

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/eI2kQ7/3)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?P<a>\d+\.\d{2})(?P<supplierPrice>.+)$
```

[Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/nZ9wB2/2)

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression syntax is incorrect, you are missing a quantifier after you initial character class in this case it only allows "one" number. Secondly, you are trying to use the concatenation operator (`'.'`) to join both of your named groups together. As well, the last named group is not matching anything.

The following should work for you.

```
preg_match('/(?P<a>[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2})(?P<supplierPrice>\S+)/', $line, $matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   preg_match("/(\d{2}\.\d{2})(\d{2}\S{3}\d{2}\S{3})/U", $line, $matches);
   print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case it does not match, because you only allow one digit before the dot

```
[0-9]\.
```

Should use

```
[0-9]+\.
```

if you want any digits before the dot. Then you shall match everything else with

```
.*
```

And then the result should be

```
preg_match("/(?P<a>[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2})(?P<supplierPrice>.*)/", $line, $matches);
```

Or using \d instead of [0-9]

```
preg_match("/(?P<a>\d+\.\d{2})(?P<supplierPrice>.*)/", $line, $matches);
```